# Pass a UImage to a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to pass an image loaded from a UIImage instance to a UIImageView in a DetailViewController. I can see I am getting pulling he image path successfully, and accessing the .gif file as seen in my NSLogs () :

```
2011-02-09 10:52:13.404 WorldGovernments[31443:207] pathToMap = af-map.gif
2011-02-09 10:52:13.406 WorldGovernments[31443:207] detail map is: <UIImage: 0x4e44a80>
```

I am uncertain on how to pass this image to `MapDetailsViewController` in the following method?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

MapDetailsViewController *dvController = [[MapDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapDetailsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

NSDictionary* tempDict=[sortedCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *pathToMap = [tempDict objectForKey:@"map"];

NSLog(@"pathToMap = %@",pathToMap);

UIImage *detailMap = [UIImage imageNamed:pathToMap];

NSLog(@"detail map is: %@",detailMap);

MapDetailsViewController.selectedImageView.image = detailMap;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
//dvController = nil;


}
```

I know I am doing something horribly wrong in this line :

```
MapDetailsViewController.selectedImageView.image = detailMap;
```

Since I get this error when I build:

```
Request for member 'image' in something not a structure or union
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MapDetailsViewController.selectedImageView` should be `dvController.selectedImageView.image = detailMap;`.

Comment: in `MapDetailsViewController`, you have to define **selectedImageView** as a `UIImageView`, using `@property` and in your **.m**, `@synthesize`

Comment: Thanks...deleted my other comment before  I saw your response.. Will try that

Comment: That cleared that up ... but still nothing is loaded into the UIImageView? Seems to be wired up correctly in IB...

Comment: Is **`af-map.gif`** in your app bundle?

Comment: Yes it is. Is the NSlog for " detail map is : " a clue? Or does that look correct?

Comment: Thats not what I mean. Of course NSLog will show it exists becuase it is in your NSDictionary. YOu have to make sure that the **af-map.gif** file is included in your project files list and that it is copied with your bundle resources. If the gif is not in your bundle, then thats why it is not showing.

Comment: Are you using a XIB? If so, connect it.

Comment: I am .. but actually what fixed it was adding : [self.view addSubview:dvController.view];  And also [dvController.selectedImageView setImage:detailMaps];     Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

change

`MapDetailsViewController.selectedImageView.image = detailMap;`

to

`dvController.selectedImageView.image = detailMap;`